# React - Lifecycle behaviour (componentDidMount) changes between local dev and production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a strange issue with my react app (created with create-react-app) When i am running locally everything works perfectly, but when i then run the app in production with npm run build componentDidMount (or just the lifecycle in general) starts acting up. Specifically, actions that *do not* cause a component to mount/re-mount in development does it in production (and these remounts are not wanted)

Some more specifics. I am creating an app where users can add draggable components (using [react-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable)) to a screen to create *views*. These views are persistent so i store the component x+y coordinates in an array of objects and save them to storage. When the page loads, the array is fetched and the view is populated using the saved coordinates. When a component is moved, there is a callback to update it's coordinates in the array and save them to storage.

**The code**

Parent view component:

```
populateComponents = () => {
      let components = this.state.componentPositions.map((c) =>
      <DraggableFunctionComponent id={c.componentName} key={c.componentName}
                                  x={c.x} y={c.y} moveEnabled={this.state.moveEnabled}
      />
      this.setState({ components: components })

          //In render
    <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
          {this.state.components}
    </div>
```

And then in the DraggableFunctionComponent:

```
<Draggable disabled={!props.moveEnabled} position={{x: x, y:y}} onStop={handleStop}>
      <div>    
         <MyOtherComponent /> //This does some API-calls etc. when mounted
        </div>
</Draggable>

//Set initial position from what is saved in storage
useEffect(() => {
    setX(props.x);
    setY(props.y);
  }, []);
```

**Problem One**

The "moveEnabled"-prop is used to disable movement of the Draggable. It is done for all components in the parent view component by changing the value of the "moveDisabled" state property. If this is changed locally, the component does not remount (which is desired). In production (npm run build/serve), however, all components are remounted when that prop is changed.

```
 setMovement = () => {
    const movement = this.state.movementEnabled;
    this.setState({ movementEnabled: !movement }, this.populateComponents)
  };
```

**Problem Two**

Adding a new component (which pushes a new component with x and y positions set to 0 in the state-held componentPositions array in the parent component) causes a full remount in production but *not* locally.

**Problem Three**
I've also noticed that componentDidMount is called multiple times (3) in production but only once locally when the page is reloaded. That is, if there is a component in the view it will (seemingly) mount 2 additional times. So, this behaviour doesn't seem to pertain to only when something in the state is actually changed by the user - it happens "by default".

**Summary**
I am not a react expert at all and there are probably lots of errors/problematic design patterns in the above code which very well could be the cause of this behaviour. However, i am confused as to why i don't see the results of this locally as well? I have found very little info on behavioural changes between local and built versions of React apps.

Comment: that would be big issue man